# Maximum number of results for realtime API

Tags: real-time, google-analytics-api

We have a user who is getting 1000 results back from a realtime API query but is expecting more.

From the docs:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime#resource

It does not appear that the realtime API response contains a facility for paging.

Is it correct to assume this API endpoint:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get

Can return a maximum of 1000 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that real-time is still beta.   The real-time request doesn't include a next link which means there is no way to get extra data back.

Try setting &max-results=10000 see what that returns.   The max rows for the Reporting API is 10000, however I have been unable to find any information on what the max number you can set in the Real-time API is.   Real-time isn't returning an error if I set it to 10000 however I don't have an account with that many real-time users so I cant test it.   I am going to send Google an email to see if I can get a verification what the max number is for the real-time api.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga:78110423&metrics=rt:activeUsers&access_token={accessToken}&max-results=10000
```

You might want to add a issue request to [issues - google analytics](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list) requesting that they add nextlink at the very least.

Comment: I have now added a request for this feature (https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=859) - please star the feature if you need it to show your support!

Comment: Good issue there.   stared